# Detect if 3 text characters or more in form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to use jQuery to detect if form fields and text fields have 3 or more characters entered in to them and if so, I would like to hide the background image.

Currently I'm achieving partial goals; hiding the background image on `focus` but the problem with this is that after the user types or selects etc, and moves to a different form field, the background image reappears..

```
input.required:focus { 
    background-image: none; 
}
textarea.required:focus { 
    background-image: none; 
}
```

Comment: It would be better to ask just one question at a time. Where's your jQuery attempt at a solution?

Comment: If you don't need to support older browser or Safari, you could use `required` and `pattern` attributes with CSS `:valid` selector, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/536csg77/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "input, textarea" ).on( "change blur", function() {
    var inputValue = $( this ).val();
    if( inputValue .length > 3 ) {
      $( this ).addClass( "moreThan3" );
    } else {
      $( this ).removeClass( "moreThan3" );
    }
  });
});
```

css

```
input.moreThan3, input.required:focus { background-image: none; }
textarea.moreThan3, textarea.required:focus { background-image: none; }
```

Comment: You are missing comma there: `"input textarea"` and i'm not sure the purpose of binding `blur` event here?

Comment: HERE http://jsfiddle.net/5pg7wrf1/ is working. Try putting 4 characters ( I added the keyup event, but is not necessary in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement on [RiccardoC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5566950/riccardoc) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762489/856268):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "input textarea" ).on( "change blur", function() {
    var inputValue = $( this ).val();
    $( this ).toggleClass( "moreThan3", inputValue.length > 3 );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form1').on('focus keypress keyup keydown click',function(){
  var changer = true;
  $('#form1').find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function(){
   if($(this).val().length<3){changer = false;}
  });
  if(changer){$('body').css('background-image','none');}
  else{$('body').css('background-image','url(image)');}
 });
});
```

```css
body{background-image:url('image');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text" />
</form>
```